# Visual shader dropdown missing

Tags: shaders, godot-4

I can't seem to create a visual shader in godot 4, in order to use the visual shader editor.

what am I missing?

[image: shader dropdown box]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. After you choose to make a New Shader (the option you see), Godot will ask the type in the Create Shader window:

[image: Shader types options in the Create Shader window]

Comment: Thanks :D That menu *could* be easier to access!